# PointCloud upsampling

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, oversampling, pcl

I have a small pointcloud. From a space point of vies it can be considered a 4x4 matrix:

```
-------------------------
|  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |
-------------------------
|  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |
-------------------------
|  8  |  9  | 10  | 11  |
-------------------------
| 12  | 13  | 14  | 15  |
-------------------------
```

I Want to to perform a supereasy upsampling strategy.
Increase the resolution of an upsampling factor (uf), the new matrix will be (4uf)x(4uf) and insert in the new samples the values of the correspondant old measuremnt. In other words, it is like substituting each cell of the (4x4) matrix with a (uf)x(uf) submatrix with values all equal of the cell of the matrix 4x4.

To make an example in the example matrix I gave, if upsampling factor is 2, i would have

```
---------------------------------
|  0|0  |  1|1  |  2|2  |  3|3  |
|  ---  |  ---  |  ---  |  ---  |
|  0|0  |  1|1  |  2|2  |  3|3  |
---------------------------------
|  4|4  |  5|5  |  6|6  |  7|7  |
|  ---  |  ---  |  ---  |  ---  |
|  4|4  |  5|5  |  6|6  |  7|7  |
---------------------------------
|  8|8  |  9|9  |  10|10  |  11|11  |
|  ---  |  ---  |  -----  |  -----  |
|  8|8  |  9|9  |  10|10  |  11|11  |
----------------------------------------
|  12|12  |  13|13  |  14|14  |  15|15  |
|  -----  |  -----  |  -----  |  -----  |
|  12|12  |  13|13  |  14|14  |  15|15  |
----------------------------------------
```

I would like to use PCL library, do you know any example? Can you give me an hint on how to do this?
By the way I am usign ROS2, I just need to upsample a pointcloud coming from a TOF sensors

I tried to search for exaples in PCL library and the only things I could find were a resampling method tutorail, and some  methods and structure recalling upsample, but I could not understand none of them

Comment: You could try upsampling with help of pcl::MovingLeastSquares. You should finde some examples.